# If $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are analytic and their power series expansions agree to second order, can a change of variables to one make them agree exactly?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

In proving Stirling's approximation in their book *Special Functions and Orthogonal Polynomials*, the authors make a claim:

Since the functions $u e^{1 - u}$ and $e^{-(u-1)^2}$ agree to second order at $u = 1$, there is an analytic change of variables $u \to s$ such that:

\begin{equation}
ue^{1 - u} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}s^2}
\end{equation}

and: $u'(s) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i s^i$ where $a_0 \neq 0$.

The given functions do not agree to second order, as can easily be checked by Taylor Expansion or direct differentiation. There is a missing factor of one half -- the functions $u e^{1 - u}$ and $e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u-1)^2}$ agree to second order. I still don't see how to get the change of variables. I do recall from complex analysis that when a function's power series starts with a m-th order term then one can change variables, in in the new variables the power series will simply be $w^m$ where $w$ is the new variable, but I fail to connect this to the above statement.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help, but [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x*e%5E(1-x)%3De%5E(-1%2F2*y%5E2)+for+y) might get you started, at least.

Comment: This is too specific to the functions given in the description, I was just trying to contextualize why I asked the question. Sure you can try to find an explicit formula for the change of variables in a specific case, but can you do this in *general* based on the assumption of agreement to second order?

Comment: If $f$ is analytic and $f(z) = C z^n+o(z^n), C \ne 0$ there is $a$ locally bi-analytic (ie. $a'(0) \ne 0$) such that $f(a(z))= z^n$.

Here $f(z) = (1+z) e^{1-(1-z)}-1,g(z) = e^{-z^2}-1, n=2$ so that locally $f(a(z)) = z^2= g(b(z))$ and $ f(z)= g(b(a^{-1}(z)), g(z) = f(a(b^{-1}(z))$

Comment: @reuns cool argument there. I'll accept it as an answer.